# Using web.debug.config/web.release.config in a Website project?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, web-config, vs-web-site-project

I have been reading about *web.config* transformation feature of VS2010 (web.debug.config/web.release.config), and all of them talk about *WebApplication* projects. **What about WebSite projects?** Can I use these transformations in a WebSite, or only in a WebApplication?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

See

- [Using Web.config Transformation in Web Site Projects](http://andrewtwest.com/2010/02/25/using-web-config-transformations-in-web-site-projects/) by Andy West
- [How to "Package/Publish" Web Site project using VS2010 and MsBuild](http://www.zvolkov.com/clog/2010/05/18/how-to-packagepublish-web-site-project-using-vs2010-and-msbuild/) by Andrei Volkov

Comment: So, I'm curious... is that a _yes_ or a _no_?

Comment: @Mr. Disappointment It's a yes but you need some hacks and workarounds.

Answer (score 1):

**Updated:**

http://vishaljoshi.blogspot.com/2010/05/applying-xdt-magic-to-appconfig.html

From the new article (second paragraph):

> there is no official/supported  implementation of XDT for any other project type than Web Application Projects

Comment: In the article they said web projects (File/New/Project...). That is different from a website (File/New/Web Site...). Thanks anyway.

Comment: I linked a new article that has some good information. If I find anything else, i'll be sure to add it.